# RxJava 2.0 - how to emit Observable from Completables

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Let's say I have something like

```
Completable doTask();
```

What I want to implement is a stream that emits an item just("Completed") after doTask() completes.

For Observable, I can do doTask().map(f -> just("Completed")); 
But how can I do it for Completable if it completes without emitting anything by nature?

Comment: Use `Single`. `Completable`s are for valueless termination.

Comment: The thing is, I can't change that Completable since it is provided by api. Maybe I can use doTask().toSingleDefault(true).map(t -> just("Completed"))?

Answer (score 0):

You were right in your comment, but instead use `doTask().toSingleDefault("Completed");`

Comment: What's the difference with/without .complete()?

Comment: The answer is just generic, in your particular case it would look like this:
`doTask().toSingleDefault("Completed");`

Comment: Was just a hint that you do not need to use `toSingleDefault(true).map(t -> just("Completed"))`